# SFMC REST API how to get objects with modifiedDate condition?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I am trying to use SFMC REST API to get a list of objects has been modified in 24 hours.
Below are the documentation for campaigns. Only three parameters are available: page, pageSize, orderBy in Get Campaigns method.

https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/hub/campaigns/getCampaignCollection.html

Is it possible to specify modifiedDate greater than a given datetime value in query string? in SFMC SOAP API, I can apply a simple/complex filter part, but this function is not mentioned in REST API documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't filter on a date range using the REST API. You will have to retrieve all campaigns (perhaps limiting by `$pageSize` if you anticipate the number of campaigns created daily to be under a certain number) and sort by `ModifiedDate DESC` (which is the default). You will then have to parse and filter the response payload (using your code).